# Change part of string in a file using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file in which each line contains one timestamp as a part of that line. The timestamp format is `1996-07-04 00:00:00.0` . I want to convert this to `1996-07-04 00:00:00` without the millisecond in each line. I tried using `re.sub()` method in Python but it replaces it with the value given by me and does not retain the original timestamp.
I was using

```
re.sub("(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d)", "replace without millisec", cell)
```

The 2nd parameter is my problem.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: If the timestamps are strings can you not do slicing `[:-2]`?

Comment: Basically, nobody won't be able to help you if you don't provide the faulting regexp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex that will capture what you need to keep, and then use the backreference to restore it after a sub replacement:

```
\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+\b
```

Replace with `\1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT5mK8/1)

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hbBZG4) code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+\b')
test_str = u"1996-07-04 00:00:00.0"
print re.sub(p, r"\1", test_str)
```

Note that you do not have to repeat the same subpatterns like `\d\d\d\d`, just use a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{n}` where `n` is the number of times you need the subpattern to repeat. You can even set minimum and maximum boundaries like `{1,4}`, or just the minimum `{2,}`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Can you tell what does r"\1" does? I am new to python.

Comment: Please check the official [`re.sub` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): It is a backreference to the text captured by the first capturing group (the subpattern inside the first group of round brackets). You can even use `\g<1>` instead of just `\1`.